# Get Group id in customer_group_save_after event

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How to get magento saved group id or group detail in `customer_group_save_after` event.

I tried below code but no luck

```
public function addCustomerGroupHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $event              = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer           = $event->getGroup(); /* not working */
    $customer           = $event->getGroup()->getId; /* not working */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$event->getObject()` instead of `$event->getGroup()`

This is because in `Mage_Customer_Model_Group` the `$_eventObject` variable is not overridden, so falls back to its definition in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

An example of this variable being correctly applied is in 
`Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` where you can see

```
protected $_eventObject = 'customer';
```